# Exporting Object and strings to CSV using Powershell

Tags: powershell

The purpose of this code is to transfer files from one location to another and to log whether the transfer was a success or a failure.

Everything works except I am having issues with the log.  I want the log to be in CSV format and there to be 3 columns: success/failure, from location, and to location.  This is outputting the results all into rows with one column.

I've tried the Export-Csv option but that looks for objects/properties so only displays the length(I have strings too).  Add-content works but there is only one column.  Any suggestions?

```
#LOCATION OF CSV
$csv = Import-Csv C:\test2.csv
#SPECIFY DATE     (EXAMPLE-DELETE FILES > 7 YEARS.  7 YEARS=2555 DAYS SO YOU WOULD ENTER "-2555" BELOW)
$Daysback = "-1"
#FILE DESTINATION
$storagedestination = "C:\Users\mark\Documents\Test2"
#LOG LOCATION
$loglocation = "C:\Users\mark\Documents\filetransferlog.csv"
$s = "SUCCESS"
$f = "FAIL"


$CurrentDate = Get-Date
foreach ($line in $csv) {
    $Path = $line | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
    $DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($DaysBack)

    $objects = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Select-Object FullName, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete } 

    foreach ($object in $objects) {
        try 
        {
            $sourceRoot = $object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
            Copy-Item -Path $sourceRoot -Recurse -Destination $storagedestination 
            Remove-Item -Path $sourceRoot -Force -Recurse
            $temp = $s, $sourceRoot, $storagedestination
            $temp | add-content $loglocation
        }
        catch
        {
            $temp2 = $f, $sourceRoot, $storagedestination
            $temp2 | add-content $loglocation
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty` are superfluous, simply attach the property name to the variable name => `$Path = $line.FullName`
Why calculate `$DatetoDelete` inside the foreach every time?
Output the success/fail to a [PSCustomObject] and gather them in a variable assigned directly to the foreach.

Untested:

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\test2.csv  
$Daysback = "-1"                
$destination = "C:\Users\mark\Documents\Test2"
$loglocation = "C:\Users\mark\Documents\filetransferlog.csv"
$s = "SUCCESS"
$f = "FAIL"

$CurrentDate  = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.Date.AddDays($DaysBack)

$Log = foreach ($line in $csv) {
    $objects = Get-ChildItem $line.FullName -Rec | 
        Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete
    foreach ($object in $objects) {
        $Result = $s
        $sourceRoot = $object.FullName
        try {
            Copy-Item   -Path $sourceRoot -Recurse -Destination $destination 
            Remove-Item -Path $sourceRoot -Recurse -Force
        } catch {
            $Result = $f
        }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Success/Fail' = $Result
            Source         = $sourceRoot
            Destination    = $destination
        }
    }
}
$Log | Export-Csv $loglocation -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I see what you did.  This worked perfectly!  The custom object is exactly what I was missing and you're right about the efficiency of the code.  P.S. I did see your edit for the result.  Thank you.